# CSS Transition effect issue while removing a class with click function

Tags: jquery, css

I have a Div with two classes. **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/dusofnct/1/)**

**HTML**

```
<div class="plug slide-down">   
</div>
```

This div initially stays at the bottom of the page. but when I click on the div I added click function to remove the .slide-down and div moves at the top.

**JS**

```
$('.plug').click(function(){
    $(this).removeClass("slide-down");
});
```

Upto this it's working fine but when I click on the div it quickly moves at the top.
I wanted to move this div at top with some sliding effect. I tried to add CSS transition but not working somehow. What I need to do so that this div moves bottom to top with some sliding effect ?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Try looking into jQuery.animate.  You could do something similar to this:

```
$('.plug').on('click', function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.animate({ top: 0, height: 300 }, function() {
        $this.removeClass('slide-down');
    });
});
```

[Here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dusofnct/5/)

Comment: Not much familiar with jQery .animate but after applying your code didn't see any effect of sliding. :(

Comment: I see this Still goes fast at top

Answer (score 1):

instead of `bottom: -250px;` try using `transform:translateY(250px);`

demo - http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/dusofnct/4/

```
.slide-down {
    transform:translateY(250px);
    z-index: 999;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom:0;
}
.plug {
    background:red;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 0px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
    -moz-box-shadow: 2px 0px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
    box-shadow: 2px 0px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
    height:300px;
    transition: all 2s;
}
```

Comment: Your solution working great but what if No height is given on Plugin and it's given on .slider how I can show animation with this scenario.
Example : http://jsfiddle.net/dusofnct/8/ 

Beside Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Since you were using `bottom` to set the div location, you should continue using `bottom` with jQuery animate:

```
$('.plug').click(function(){
    $(this).animate({
        'bottom': '170px',
    },1000,function(){
        //$(this).removeClass('slide-down');
    });
});
```

<kbd>[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/dusofnct/7/)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks for the Solution but what I can do with this scenario:
http://jsfiddle.net/dusofnct/8/

Here height is given on the .slide-down  and bottom is 0px;

Answer (score 0):

Use this code, it animate `top` property, but you should change your slide-down class: http://jsfiddle.net/dusofnct/6/

CSS:

```
.slide-down{
    position: fixed;
    top: 90%;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

JS:

```
$('.slide-down').click(function(){
    $(this).animate({'top':0},1000,function(){
        $(this).removeClass('slide-down');
    });
});
```